# Best practice for creating a details view model (in Xaml)

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime

I'm creating a windows 8 application (but I suspect that any one using Xaml can help me). It basically boils down to: a page with a list of products on it, clicking on a product opens a details page.

In my composition root I resolve the view model for the first page, and set the data context appropriately, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for passing a view model to page 2 when the user selects a product.

As far as I can tell I have the following options:-

- The first viewmodel requires an abstract factory capable of creating
  a view model for page 2 with a .create(product) method, this would be passed in to the first view models constructor
- Have the second view model implement an interface with an product property allowing me to use property injection, and pass the second view model as a parameter to the first viewmodel.
- Create a service locator which I know is considered by many to be an anti-pattern.

I'm at a bit of a loss, but I suspect the abstract factory is the right way to go, I want to get this right as the object graph is actually this (product->Step->Instruction), so any re-work could take quite a bit of time, but it basically means that my view model if I went down the abstract factory route would take three abstract factories, and the service for getting the initial list of products (and then is this a code smell given how many parameter it has!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the situation where you want to resolve the view-model in runtime (from code) factory is the way to go.

To make it easier I would also consider using some DI framework. I believe there won't be many of them for WinRT but [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=Autofac-2.6.1.841-Portable.zip) is supposed to work with metro.

Comment: This is what I thought. I am using MetroIOC so that's fine. I just wondered if having view models with such high number of parameters in its constructors was a sign of a bad design.

Comment: IMHO in combination with dependency injection, higher number of constructor arguments should be fine. You set them up in the DI configuration anyway. 

Of course when the number grows substantially you should refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection might be the way to do it if you are building something big. Personally I usually just pass the parameters in the Navigate() call and initialize the view model using these parameters in the OnNavigatedTo handler.

Comment: Thats what I have been doing (but passing a view model). I meant to say thanks to you as I have been doing a lot of image processing in windows 8 and quiet a few of your posts have helped me out!